# DependencyService.Get returns null when setting is "Link All"

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My Xamarin.iOS app (Xamarin.Forms) runs fine as long as I have the iOS project's properties -> iOS Build -> Linker Behavior set to "Don't Link" or "Link Framework SDKs only". But when it's set to "Link All" - `DependencyService.Get<ISomething>();` returns null.

Why is that? / How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Linker can't tell that a class you only instantiate via DI is actually being used.  To get around that, add the [Preserve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker) attribute to your class

```
[Preserve (AllMembers = true)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent a _lot_ of time trying to figure this one out.